# crear array asociativo y mostrarlo en una tabla horizontal

Tags: php, laravel, array

ya utilice rowspan y no me funciona como quiero los datos se mantienen muy desordenado no se ordenan como es, ademas no me cuadra los datos según si es dependientes de otros, ademas el código tiene un padres y sus hijos y esos hijos tienes muchos hijos pero ala vez lo tengo mostrar tabla horizontal de esta manera en forma vertical me funciona bien la cuestión es pasar esos datos de una manera horizontal en una tabla muestro verticalmente los datos en foto muestro por colores el padre es de color rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas quiero se vea de una manera mas organizada como lo muestra en excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código lo tengo de esta manera

```
@foreach ($project->administrators as $administrator)
<p>  {{$administrator->name}}</p>
@foreach($project->phases as $phase)            
    <p style="background: #FD2D00 !important;">{{$phase->name}}</p>

    @foreach ($phase->activities as $activity)

        @if ($activity->parent_id==null)

            <p style="background: #FDF500;">{{$activity->name}}</p>


        @endif

        @foreach($activity->activities as $especifics)

                <p style="background: #86FD00;">{{$especifics->name}}</p>

            @foreach($especifics->products as $product)

                   <p style="background: #006BFD;">{{$product->name}}</p>

                @foreach($product->productdetails as $productdetail)

                      <p style="background: #7243BB;">{{$productdetail->name}}</p>

                    @foreach($productdetail->evidence as $evidence )

                           <p style="background: #FF00FB;">{{$evidence->path}}</p>

                    @endforeach
                @endforeach    
            @endforeach 
        @endforeach    
    @endforeach 
@endforeach 

@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola, no he revisado a fondo tu código, pero al ver esa ***pirámide*** infernal de `@foreach` me parece que tu problema es de algoritmo. Debe existir una forma más simple y menos dolorosa de realizar la tarea. ¿Puedes agregar la estructura de datos sobre la cual trabajas? Entre lo que dices de padres, hijos, tíos y cuñados me pierdo y no es fácil enteder lo que deseas. Saludos

Comment: hola amigo es tengo realizar un reporte color rojo muestro primer nivel, el segundo color amarillo es hijo que volvió padre, ademas ese hijo-padre , tiene otro hijo que también se volvió padre y así la cadena, lo que necesito es colocar en orden de forma horizontal esos datos ya intentado de miles de maneras

Comment: si yo también e pensado mirar por medio otra forma por medio de un for pero la cuestión no los datos me muestran de una manera ordenada de forma vertical, pero cuando lo paso a horizontal hay es donde tengo el problema mas grande